# While Updating Xamarin froms to 5.0.0.2401 ListView Getting Crashed in Xamarin iOS

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, renderer

Getting This Error After Updating Xamarin Forms :

Could not resolve type with token 0100029a from typeref (expected class 'ObjCRuntime.DisposableObject' in assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'

Anyone has any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue about that is here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15280

The fix is to make sure that you are using the latest Xamarin.iOS versions to compile your code. I think you need 15.4+

Comment: https://xcodereleases.com/